# $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl not working when change to new directory path

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I did a popover function with ionic 1 for my app. It works fine.However,
my code not working if I move from the original directory to new directory path.

`popover.html` **is contains** inside `page.html`. It is part of the code of `page.html`

How can I change the right directory in the code? I try with

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('/all/page/popover.html', {
              scope: $scope
           }).then(function(popover) {
              $scope.popover = popover;
           });
```

but it does not work

**Original directory path**

`/www/js/controllers/page.js`

`/www/templates/page.html`

**new directory path**

`/www/all/page/page.js`

`/www/all/page/page.html`

page.js (current working code)

```
 $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('popover.html', {
              scope: $scope
           }).then(function(popover) {
              $scope.popover = popover;
           });

           $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
              $scope.popover.show($event);
           };

           $scope.closePopover = function() {
              $scope.popover.hide();
           };

           //Cleanup the popover when we're done with it!
           $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              $scope.popover.remove();
           });

           // Execute action on hide popover
           $scope.$on('popover.hidden', function() {
              // Execute action
           });

           // Execute action on remove popover
           $scope.$on('popover.removed', function() {
              // Execute action
           });
```

page.html(current working code)

```
   <button class="button" ng-click="openPopover($event)"><i class="ion-android-more-vertical"></i></button>

  <script id = "popover.html" type = "text/ng-template">
    <ion-popover-view>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list" ng-click="popover.hide()">
          <a class="item" href="#/app/morepage">
            Apple
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#/app/morepage1">
            Orange
          </a>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-popover-view>
  </script>
```

In app.js

```
    .state('app.page', {
    url: '/page',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: '/all/page/page.html',
            controller: 'page'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: the directory say page.html and the fromTemplateUrl says popover.html its typo error???

Comment: @JesusCarrasco popover.html is contain inside page.html. It is part of it. This example would have more details https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_popover.htm

Comment: if it is inside the page.html wraped in the <script> you dont need to change the fromTemplateUrl adding the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to demostrate if you want to change **fromTemplateUrl**

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('/all/page/page.html', {
          scope: $scope
       }).then(function(popover) {
          $scope.popover = popover;
       });
```

in the page.html in the `<script>` change this

```
<script id = "/all/page/popover.html" type = "text/ng-template">
<ion-popover-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list" ng-click="popover.hide()">
      <a class="item" href="#/app/morepage">
        Apple
      </a>
      <a class="item" href="#/app/morepage1">
        Orange
      </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

the reason why `$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('popover.html')` works its because in the page.html its relative name was the same.

If you change the above, needs change the html. its represent relative paths. if physically existe the file, i really need to be in the path you indicate.

Comment: It does not work as `popover.html` is a script inside `page.html`. Hopefully you clear of that. Thus, there is no path as `/all/page/popover.html`

Comment: in app.js the templateURL has set to `/all/page/page.html`